# Is it correct to use the <time> tag for displaying dates in HTML5

Tags: html

Is it correct this code for displaying a date?

```
<time class="entry-date" datetime="2010-09-27T10:50:15+00:00" pubdate>27/09/2010</time>
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: I meant whether it is semantically correct or there is another better option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup - that's correct. Have a look at this draft spec to see the valid date time strings: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#global-dates-and-times.

Your time represents 27th September 2010, 3:00pm UTC.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is the one you should use according to:

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_reference.asp

> The  tag defines a time or a
>   date, or both.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's both syntactically and semantically correct:

- The `time` tag should be used to define a date and/or time
- The syntax of the `datetime` attribute is correct and passes W3C:s HTML5 validator
- The `pubdate` attribute is also fine, assuming that the `time` tag is inside an `article` tag and that the `time` tag actually specifies the publication time of the article